# The name of a 80s or 90s animated series where a trio goes on an adventure?

Tags: story-identification, animation

I cannot for the life of me find this show. I’m not sure where it aired but I remember a few details. It was fantasy like and a blonde protagonist goes on a journey with a man and girl. The girl can understand what trees say and had a pet crow that may or may not carry her if she wants? Oh and there was an invisibility cloak that they used often.

Comment: Was the blonde protagonist male or female?

Comment: And what colour hair did the other two characters have?

Comment: Just putting this out there in case some details were misremembered. Swap out the crow for a monkey bird and lose the cloak of invisibility and you have Pirates of Dark Water.

Comment: Sounds kind of like the [Deltora Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(TV_series)) show that FuzzyBoots helped me id a while back. It has blonde protagonist named Lief acompanied by man and a girl named Jasmine, who understands the language of trees and has a pet raven. Lief also had a kind of invisibility cloak. Only it isn't from 90s, but from late 2000s.